# Can I add more functions to System.Linq.Dynamic.Core?

Tags: parsing, dynamic, formula

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to parse custom statistical templates, and was wondering if it is possible to somehow extend the library's functionality to parse more mathematical functions. Specifically, I needed in this instance to calculate the absolute value of a variable. I have managed to do this with the already supported "iif" function (i.e. "`iif(a>-a, a, -a)`"), but I was wondering if there is a way to extend the library to add an "abs()" function, and similarly other functions I may need in the future (such as square root etc).

Any pointers to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) library is not really designed for this extensibility.

However, you can take a look at the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.cs` for examples, like the `IIF` you already mention.